# How to add the CSRF field to a form generated with jquery.(Laravel 5)

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5, csrf

Laravel requires you to write your form like this.

```
<form method ="POST" action="whatever">
    {{ csrf_field() }} 
</form>
```

I've already created around 15 forms with jquery in my website with code like the following.

```
$("#formholder).append("<form id='myForm' method='post' action ='whatever'></form>");
```

My Question is:

How do I add the csrf field on these forms created with jquery?

Answer (score 5):

Put this meta tag into the main Blade template with other meta tags:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Then you'll be able to access it with this from JS:

```
$('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token

Comment: var a=  $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
   // alert(a);
   var divForm ="<form id='myForm' action='standardForm' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'></form>"
    $("#formHolder").append(divForm);
    $("#myForm").append(a);  // I tried this.This simply shows a value on the page.Laravel still throws the csrf error

Answer (score 2):

**Alternatively**:
Add following input field.

```
<input name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" type="hidden">
```

to the form

**Updated:** In your JQuery

```
'....../><input name="_token" value="'+csrf_js_var+'" type="hidden"><......'
```

Initial Global Var or create when new blade initialized using `<script>` tag. Add following code inside that script tag and use the variable in your JQuery.

```
var csrf_js_var = "{{ csrf_token() }}" //I have used this way
```

Comment: just an idea bro, take a look at updated, this is how i did.

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1 :**  Add the following code to your main layout file.

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

**Step 2 :** Get the value of csrf token in your javascript.

```
var csrfVar = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
```

**Step 3 :** In your form append a hidden input field with value set to your csrf variable

```
$("#myForm").append("<input name='_token' value='" + csrfVar + "' type='hidden'>");
```

This has been worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can also add it globally to jQuery

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/csrf